# @ManyToMany Table fails on update

Tags: jpa, sql-update, many-to-many

I have run into a problem that I haven't been able to solve yet.

I have two entities: Service and Person, I make relation many to many for join table "Clt_Serv".person it is a parent of 2 tables : Client and Admin

```
public class Person implements Serializable {   

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="Clt_Serv",joinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="Code_Clt"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Code_Serv"))
    private Collection<Service> services;

}
```

```
public class Service implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="services")
    private Collection<Person> clients;

}

 // update

@RequestMapping(value = "/identifiant")
    public String idetifiantclient(@ModelAttribute Client personne)throws Exception {

    long idp =personne.getIdPersonne();

        if (personne.getIdPersonne()!=0) {

            metier.updatepersonne(personne);
        }
          return "redirect:/page/pageuser/"+idp;

}
```

I try for make select, add of join table `Clt_Serv` and it is good, but when I try to update `person` all information in join table `Clt_Serv` are deleted. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Better add your update code.

Comment: @Nicholas i add my function update

Comment: Looks like "metier.updatepersonne(personne);" does the actual update.

Comment: yes i use "metier.updatepersonne(personne) for update row in table person .@Nicholas